# What is the value of SIM state when "airplane mode" is turned on

Tags: android, telephony, sim-card, airplane-mode

I wonder what is the value of SIM state returned by [`TelephonyManager.getSimState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState%28%29) when "airplane mode" is turned on? This seems to be not directly specified anywhere in the SDK specification.

Actually I need to get SIM operator code (i.e. MCC+MNC) using [`getSimOperator()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimOperator%28%29) method, but JavaDoc states that to use that method:

> SIM state must be [SIM_STATE_READY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_READY)

**UPDATE**

I tested it under emulator and it returns [`SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN) (which is described by javadoc as a "transition between states") after airplane mode is switched on. However I would like to know whether it is a common behavior on Android phones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching Android 4.1 sources I found the following code in one of the private classes [`com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccCard.java):

```
public State getState() {
  if (mState == null) {
      switch(mPhone.mCM.getRadioState()) {
          /* This switch block must not return anything in
           * State.isLocked() or State.ABSENT.
           * If it does, handleSimStatus() may break
           */
          case RADIO_OFF:
          case RADIO_UNAVAILABLE:
          case SIM_NOT_READY:
          case RUIM_NOT_READY:
              return State.UNKNOWN;
          case SIM_LOCKED_OR_ABSENT:
          case RUIM_LOCKED_OR_ABSENT:
              //this should be transient-only
              return State.UNKNOWN;
          case SIM_READY:
          case RUIM_READY:
          case NV_READY:
              return State.READY;
          case NV_NOT_READY:
              return State.ABSENT;
      }
  } else {
      return mState;
  }

  Log.e(mLogTag, "IccCard.getState(): case should never be reached");
  return State.UNKNOWN;
}
```

So `State.UNKNOWN` would be returned whenever radio state is one of [RADIO_OFF](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/CommandsInterface.java#30) or [RADIO_UNAVAILABLE](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/CommandsInterface.java#31). Then `State.UNKNOWN` will be converted to `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` constant by `TelephonyManager.getSimState()` method.

As the conclusion: when airplane mode is turned on `getSimState` will return `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Can you please fix the links to RADIO_OFF and RADIO_UNAVAILABLE ?

Comment: @NiravZaveri done. Please note, that starting from Android 4.2 `IccCard` was converted to interface and deprecated. The related logic is now located at [IccCardProxy](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/IccCardProxy.java#264) class. And internally `State.NOT_READY` is used when radio is turned off. Nevertheless it's not available in public API and it is converted to `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` in the `getSimState()` method.

Comment: Thanks.
What happens with me usually is even when Airplane mode is on, it goes to Sim_State_Ready even in Airplane mode, but also returns simSerialNumber as NULL then after. That's why I wanted to look at the source code.

Comment: @NiravZaveri What Android version do you have?

Comment: I have Android 4.3 on this phone where I am testing the code.
It's a Redmi phone (MIUI version 45).

Comment: @NiravZaveri Then I can suggest you to look here: http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/uicc/ I will have a look at it once I have time.

Comment: Sure, will have a look at it and put up any questions that I have further, on here.

Answer (score 2):

yes, this is the common behavior on android phones.
see the implementation of the getSimState() method from the TelephonyManager class:

```
public int getSimState() {
    String prop = SystemProperties.get(TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_SIM_STATE);
    if ("ABSENT".equals(prop)) {
        return SIM_STATE_ABSENT;
    }
    else if ("PIN_REQUIRED".equals(prop)) {
        return SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED;
    }
    else if ("PUK_REQUIRED".equals(prop)) {
        return SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED;
    }
    else if ("NETWORK_LOCKED".equals(prop)) {
        return SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED;
    }
    else if ("READY".equals(prop)) {
        return SIM_STATE_READY;
    }
    else {
        return SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple, since `TelephonyManager.getSimState` does not show us the mapping between phone and sim states (see my own answer for the code which is responsible for that). Giving you +1 anyway for looking at the source ;)