# Possible ways of geting Sim State as UNKNOWN

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

Can anybody explain, what are possible ways of getting Sim State as UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 2):

> public static final int **SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN**
>
> SIM card state: Unknown. Signifies that the SIM is in transition
>   between states. For example, when the user inputs the SIM pin under
>   PIN_REQUIRED state, a query for sim status returns this state before
>   turning to SIM_STATE_READY.

Also  look at the implementation of the `getSimState()` method from the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class.

```
    public State getState() {
      if (mState == null) {
      switch(mPhone.mCM.getRadioState()) {
          /* This switch block must not return anything in
           * State.isLocked() or State.ABSENT.
           * If it does, handleSimStatus() may break
           */
          case RADIO_OFF:
          case RADIO_UNAVAILABLE:
          case SIM_NOT_READY:
          case RUIM_NOT_READY:
              return State.UNKNOWN;
          case SIM_LOCKED_OR_ABSENT:
          case RUIM_LOCKED_OR_ABSENT:
              //this should be transient-only
              return State.UNKNOWN;
          case SIM_READY:
          case RUIM_READY:
          case NV_READY:
              return State.READY;
          case NV_NOT_READY:
              return State.ABSENT;
      }
  } else {
      return mState;
  }

  Log.e(mLogTag, "IccCard.getState(): case should never be reached");
  return State.UNKNOWN;
}
```

So `State.UNKNOWN` would be returned whenever radio state is one of `RADIO_OFF` or `RADIO_UNAVAILABLE`. Then `State.UNKNOWN` will be converted to `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` constant by `TelephonyManager.getSimState()` method.

As a conclusion: `getSimState` will return `SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN` whenever the sim state is transitioning from one to another (e.g. When Airplane mode is turned on, between the transitions of Sim State, it will be in SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN).

Reference: [Sim State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849192/what-is-the-value-of-sim-state-when-airplane-mode-is-turned-on).